# Javascript call to in-house PHP API returns error - net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: php, iis

We have a PHP API that returns formatted postcodes from a (in this case) Ajax call from javascript.

We are running a windows 2019 server and did an upgrade to PHP8 and are now getting the error net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID whenever we try to make the call to the API.

I have downloaded the latest cacert.pem file and added the following two lines to the php.ini:

```
curl.cainfo ="C:\Program Files\PHP\v8.0\ext\cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="C:\Program Files\PHP\v8.0\ext\cacert.pem"
```

Now I am assuming that it is a PHP issue (as we upgraded to PHP8 over the weekend) but it could be something else and just a coincidence.

The issue can bee seen here: [www.postcodetools.co.uk](http://www.postcodetools.co.uk). Just attempt to use any of the examples and the console shows the error.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expiry date set for the cert?

Comment: Zachary - The cacert.pem file was downloaded this morning from the https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html site and added to the path above.
How would I check the expiry date?

Comment: I checked the SSL certificate for the domain we use for the call and it was renewed this morning and has an exprity date of 28/6/2022

Comment: What is the current time of the server making the request, ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID  is given when the certificate presented by the API server does not have a value date according to the server making the request. This might be because the cert is no longer valid or that the server making the request has its time configured incorrectly

Comment: Just checked the server and the timestamp looks OK. The issue I have is that an upgrade to PHP8 was done over the weekend AND the cert for the domain which handles the API also ran out and was renewed this morning. I am scratching my head as to which is causing the issue.

Comment: The question has been updated with a test URL

Answer (score 0):

Revoked and re-issued and re-installed the certificate for the API domain and all now works.